# Помогите создать sql запрос Sum для множества с исключением

Tags: sql, запрос, group-by

Здравствуйте 
Как посчитать Sum для каждого из списка получателей с условием что тип `Tip`=1
`PlatelshchiK` не может быть кто из списка.
Есть таблица `Plateg`
В таблице `Poluchatel`, `PlatelshchiK`, `Summ2`, `Tip`
Есть список `Poluchatel`
'0001561', 
'0001274', 
'0119900', 
'0000224', 
'4209900', 
'0024912', 
'0000224',
'0001561'
При этом исключить этих пользователей если они встречаются в `PlatelshchiK`
'0001561', 
'0001274', 
'0119900', 
'0000224', 
'4209900', 
'0024912', 
'0000224',
'0001561'
Если они будут встречаться в `PlatelshchiK`
**как не странно но такое тоже возможно оказалось**
Пример
`Poluchatel`='0001561' и `PlatelshchiK`='0001561'  - Исключить
`Poluchatel`='0001561' и `PlatelshchiK`='0000224'  - Исключить
`Poluchatel`='0001561' и `PlatelshchiK`='0024912'  - Исключить
Соответственно это правило для всех из списка `Poluchatel`

Результат примерно такой
0001561 - Сумма
0001274 - Сумма
0119900 - Сумма
0000224 - Сумма
4209900 - Сумма
0024912 - Сумма

Заранее спасибо за развернутый ответ

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Начните с публикации примера данных в виде нормально форматированного CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (можно дополнительно в виде online fiddle) и требуемого ответа для именно этих данных. С подробными пояснениями. То, как это выглядит сейчас - совершенно нечитабельно.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   Poluchatel,
   SUM(Summ2) AS SUM
FROM
   Plateg
WHERE
   TIP = 1
   AND Poluchatel NOT IN (
                          SELECT
                             PlatelshchiK
                          FROM
                             Plateg
                         )
GROUP BY
   Poluchatel
```